# Do I need a destructor if I am also using a copy constructor and overloaded = operator?

Tags: c++

So I have this code where I have the class Student which a vector with objects of class *ModuleGrade. I have a destructor in the class Student but then I have also a destructor in the overloading of = operator. Do I need to have it both times or I can just keep the destructor in the class Student and it will do the job also in the overloading of the = operator. 
I hope I managed to explain it.

**EDIT:** 
I am aware of the fact that it is better if the vector is without a * but the aim of this is to make me show I understand how * and deep copy constructor work.

Here is my code:

Student.h

```
 private:
    int studentNumber;
    vector <ModuleGrade*> gradeList;
 public:
    ~Student();
    Student(const Student& student);  // user-defined copy ctor
    Student& operator = (const Student& student);
```

Student.cpp

```
Student::~Student() 
{

    int number = gradeList.size();
    for(int i= 0; i<number; i++){
        delete gradeList[i];
    }
} 


Student::Student(const Student &student ) : Person(student) {
    //deep copy constructor
    this->studentNumber=student.studentNumber;
    int size = student.gradeList.size();
    for(int i=0; i <size; i++) {

       // ModuleGrade *m ;
        ModuleGrade *mg = new ModuleGrade(*(student.gradeList[i]));
        gradeList.push_back(mg);
    }

}

Student& Student :: operator = (const Student & student) {
    if (&student == this) return *this;
    Person :: operator=(student);
    studentNumber = student.studentNumber;

    //delete gradeList of this
    //SHOULD I DO THIS IF THERE IS A DESTRUCTOR DECLARED???
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<gradeList.size(); i++){
        delete gradeList[i];
        gradeList.clear();
    }

    //fill this with grades of student
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<student.gradeList.size(); i++) {
        ModuleGrade *m = new ModuleGrade(*(student.gradeList[i]));
        gradeList.push_back(m);

    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: If you change your member variable from `vector<ModuleGrade*>` to `vector<ModuleGrade>` you wouldn't need to `new` each of the objects in your vector, plus the compiler-generated default destructor, copy constructor, and copy-assignment operator would work without you writing any extra code.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the self memory management if I remove the * but the goal of this is to make me show I understand how the * and deep copy constructor work.

Comment: better mention that in the question. If you post something with raw owning pointers you will get complaints (and thats good ;)

Comment: Assigning does not cause automatic destruction of anything. "Some code that clears a vector" is not a destructor.

Comment: @molbdnilo How should it be then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you manage pointers then you need to ensure that pointed-to objects are cleaned up on assignment as well as on destruction.

This is why people often write the assignment operator using move and swap:

```
X& operator=(X const& other){
   X temp(other);
   swap(temp);
   return *this;
}
```

because the cleanup then only has to be written in the destructor. `swap` just exchanges contents, and the copy constructor allocates new contents.

Using move-and-swap also covers the case that you write `x=x`, as otherwise you need to explicitly test for that case in the assignment operator if you destroy the data pointed to by the object being assigned to before trying to copy the data from the other object.

Also, in real code you should use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` if you want to hold objects by pointer: you should never have to write `delete` manually, and you can often use `std::make_unique` or `std::make_shared` instead of `new` too.

Comment: So without the swap I need to have it both places? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, if you don't do move-and-swap then you need cleanup in the assignment operator and the destructor.